# Reading files into a pyspark dataframe from directories and subdirectories

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below to read all files within a directory, but I am struggling with getting the subdirectories too. I won't always know what the subdirectories are and hence cannot explicitly define it

Can anyone advise me please?

```
df = my_spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(yesterday+"/*.csv")
```

Comment: You can try `os.walk`? Also, you can specify a folder with multiple csv files, but that will work only for one level fold

Comment: can you try giving wildcards in this way and see "path/*/*"

Comment: @kikee1222 did that work, if so can you mark the question as answered, so that it helps others who face similar issue

Comment: Thanks for your help - how do I mark it as answered? I didnt know I could do that with a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Wildcards after the directory location where you wish to read all the sub directories.

```
"path/*/*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joby

> can you try giving wildcards in this way and see "path/*/*" – Joby 23
>   hours ago